# Memory consumption

Tags: memory, webmin, consumption

How there could be such a memory consumption when the total amount of RAM is 2 GB?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each application gets allocated some memory for it to use by the operating system, and it doesn't have visibility outside this memory space. This is called "virtual Memory" AFAIK. I'm not an expert so I will not go into details, but here is a post describing them.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/112380/different-memory-types-in-system-monitor